# C++ Multimap Printing

Tags: c++, multimap

I'm trying to make a name, and then give a list of courses this person has taken. Here is my code currently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    multimap<string,string> students;
    students.insert(make_pair("john","cs1"));
    students.insert(make_pair("john","cs2"));
    
        for (auto itr = students.begin(); itr != students.end(); ++itr) 
        { 
        cout << itr->first << '\t' << itr->second << '\n'; 
        } 
    
}
```

This prints out:

```
John CS1
John CS2
```

If I wanted to make it print out the first value and then print out all second values, how would I do this? Do I need to use a list as the second value or something? Or is this doable with just multimaps? For example:

```
John CS1 CS2
```

Comment: what do you mean 'print out all second values'? print out all second values that first = john?

Comment: I want it to print the first value of the map, which is John. following this, I want it to list out each value that is linked to john. Like John CS1 CS2

Answer (score 2):

You can use `equal_range` to achieve what you wanted, see:

```
    std::string current_key = "";
    for (auto itr = students.begin(); itr != students.end(); ++itr) 
    { 
        if(current_key == itr->first) {
            continue;
        } else {
            current_key = itr->first;
        }
        const auto result = students.equal_range(itr->first);
        cout << itr->first << ": ";
        for(auto it = result.first; it != result.second; ++it) {
            cout << it->second << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        
    }
```

See working example here: https://ideone.com/RqCFOk

Comment: pretty nice solution. the reason why it solved by current_key is multimap contains a **sorted** list of key-value pairs.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure of this but that's the requirement of the `std::multimap` so it should work.

Comment: This does is exactly what I need! Thank you much. Could you explain what current_key is used for an also what equal_range does for this?

Comment: You're welcome! Explanation: `equal_range` returns all elements for a given key - it's almost exactly what you needed. But we want to use it for each key exactly once. This is the purpose of `current_key`: while iterating over all the keys, given key will occur at least once, but we want to iterate over given key only once - hence we only perform printing for the first occurance of a given key. If current_key == itr->first it means we have already covered this key, so we continue and get next key.

Answer (score 0):

You'll may eventually end up creating a `class` to model a student, in the meantime, you could just iterate over the `multimap` container and check if the current key is the same as the previous:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using students_t = std::multimap<std::string, std::string>;

void print_students_list(students_t const& students)
{
    // Start printing the name of the first student and the first course (the first key-value
    // pair) if the container is not empty.
    auto student{ students.cbegin() };
    if ( student == students.cend() )
        return;    
    std::cout << std::setw(12) << std::left << student->first 
              << std::setw(8) << student->second;

    // Then iterate over the rest of the container printing the name (after a newline)
    // only if it's different from the previous one.          
    for ( auto prev{ student++ }; student != students.cend(); prev = student, ++student ) 
    { 
        if ( student->first != prev->first )
            std::cout << '\n' << std::setw(12) << student->first;
        std::cout << std::setw(8) << student->second; 
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    students_t students {
        {"john", "cs1"},
        {"john", "cs2"},
        {"Karen", "cs2"},
        {"Karen", "nc1"},
        {"Karen", "nc2"},
        {"Bob", "nc1"}
    };
    
    print_students_list(students);  
}
```